# How to throw custom http error in play framework java

Tags: java, playframework

Below is the code to save data. I want to throw http error code 422 if validation fails. But i am getting 200(OK) response. How to do that. Thanks

```
public Result saveBook()
    {
        Form<Book> bookForm = formFactory.form(Book.class).bindFromRequest();

        if(bookForm.hasErrors())
        {
            List<String> validationError = new ArrayList<>();

            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();

            result.put("code", 422);
            result.put("status", "error");

            for(ValidationError e: bookForm.allErrors())
            {
                validationError.add(e.message());
            }

            result.put("errors", Json.toJson(validationError));

            return ok(result);
        }

        Book book = bookForm.get();
        book.save();

        return ok(Json.toJson(book));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
return ok(result);
```

... is telling Play to return an `ok` (i.e. HTTP status 200) result.

The [play.mvc.Results](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/index.html) class offers shortcuts such as:

- `ok()`
- `notFound()`
- `badRequest()`
- `internalServerError()`

It does not offer a shortcut for a 422 but you can easily create one: `status(422, "...")`.

So, just replace ...

```
return ok(result);
```

... with:

```
return status(422, "your chosen status message");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting the same response what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just simply replace `return ok(Json.toJson(book));` with `return status(422)`

OR you can use the link below to see what other options do you have besides the simplest status(422) form.
 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.Status.html#Results.Status(play.api.mvc.Results.Status,%20byte[])